# R sum of values ​in columns for selected rows

Tags: r, dplyr, sum

I have the following dataset:

```
         Mark    Model      Sold
1       Skoda  Octavia     21125
2       Skoda    Fabia     19679
3        Opel    Astra     15282
4  Volkswagen     Golf     14190
5      Toyota    Yaris     14032
6      Toyota    Auris     12073
7        Ford    Focus     11126
```

I need a formula that sums the quantities sold for each brand, in order to get the result that looks like this:

```
         Mark   Total Sold
1       Skoda        40804
2        Opel        15282
3  Volkswagen        14190
4      Toyota        26105
5        Ford        11126
```

Could anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use a group by sum.  In `base R`, this can be done with `aggregate`

```
aggregate(Sold ~ Mark, df1, sum)
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(Mark) %>%
   summarise(Total = sum(Sold))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#  Mark       Total
#  <chr>      <int>
#1 Ford       11126
#2 Opel       15282
#3 Skoda      40804
#4 Toyota     26105
#5 Volkswagen 14190
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Mark = c("Skoda", "Skoda", "Opel", "Volkswagen", 
"Toyota", "Toyota", "Ford"), Model = c("Octavia", "Fabia", "Astra", 
"Golf", "Yaris", "Auris", "Focus"), Sold = c(21125L, 19679L, 
15282L, 14190L, 14032L, 12073L, 11126L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"))
```